# Unselecting a range from a selected data set

Tags: excel, unselect, vba

I am trying to unselect empty columns from my selection and save the desired selection as a new Range object.

[This is my Current Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4HLw.png)

[and this is what I desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leaby.png)

Please help me out as Google search isn't helping and I am not able to find any such methods that would solve the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Selection.Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Select
```

Selection refers to all your selected cells. Each selection will surely contain atleast a cell. Your selection may contain 100 cells or may be 20 or may be 5. But it will surely have 1 cell in it. That code is targeting the first cell in selection and identifying the current region (Data's associated with that first cell) and selecting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working now. Could you please explain what Selection.Cells(1) does (although I've seen what it does) so that I can use it as and when required.

Comment: Selection refers to all your selected cells.  Each selection will surely contain atleast a cell.  Your selection may contain 100 cells or may be 20 or may be 5.  But it will surely have 1 cell in it.  That code is targeting the first cell in selection and identifying the current region (Data's associated with that first cell) and selecting it.

Comment: @Sixthsense It would be much better if you could add your explanation to the post and not just as a comment.